# Автоинкремент в двухнаправленом списке

Tags: c++, список, структуры-данных

Пишу программу с использованием списка "вперёд-назад". Большая часть функционала работает. Проблема в автоинкременте, не пойму, почему не увеличивается номер по списку
Вот [код](http://pastebin.com/rfJQ4rzj)

Вот часть кода, в которой, вероятно, какая-то ошибка:

```
void List::Add(int key, char name[20], char type[20], float price, float massa, eat *temp)
{
    if (temp->key != 0)
            Add(key, name, type, price, massa, temp->Next);
    else{
            temp = new eat;
            temp->Next = NULL;
            temp->key = key++;
            strcpy_s(temp->name, 20, name);
            strcpy_s(temp->type, 20, type);
            temp->price = price;
            temp->massa = massa;
    }
    if (begin != NULL) //Если список не пуст
    {
            temp->Prev = end;
            end->Next = temp;
            end = temp;
    }
    else
    {
            temp->Prev = NULL;
            begin = end = temp;
    }
    cout << "Записи присвоен номер: " << temp->key << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема?

Comment: Представьте минимально компилируемую программу, которая демонстрирует проблему. Не используйте ссылки вместо конкретного кода.

Comment: Эта функция вообще не имеет смысла. Что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, добавляю элемент в список

Comment: Куда добавляете: в начало списка, в конец списка или куда-то в середину списка? Какой смысл переменной key?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, должен добавляться в конец
key - номер по списку
Потом по этой переменной обращаемся, чтобы вывести информацию в консоль определённого элемента, или удалить определённый элемент

Comment: А зачем указываете указатель на элемент списка в функции Add? Вы должны создавать элемент внутри этой функции.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, я не до конца понял что вы имеете ввиду, таким образом я и добавляю в список

Comment: Новый элемент вы должны создавать в функции Add. Поэтому никакой указатель на элемент не должен присутствовать в списке параметров функции. У вас в списке есть указатель на последний элемент. К нему вы и должны добавлять новый элемент, созданный внутри функции.

Comment: Кроме того, что вы предполагаете делать, если пользователь укажет ключ, который уже имеется в списке?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, пользователь может вводить ключ только в функции удаления или просмотра элемента

Comment: А как тогда добавить новую запись?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, вызвать метод Add
В этом-то и вся соль, должен срабатывать автоинкремент, мол новый элемент - это key++

Comment: Автоинкремент чего, параметра?

Comment: Номера по списку(key)

Answer (score 3):

Номер по списку не увеличивается потому, что temp->key = key++; сначала делает temp->key=key, а потом уже делает key++, который более нигде не используется. Т.е. его инкремент проходит в пустую. temp->key=++key; должно решить проблему. Хотя imho key должен вестись где то совершенно отдельно, например быть статическим членом класса